# how to execute an asynс function without waiting for a response on Python

Tags: python, task, scheduled-tasks, python-asyncio

I can’t execute another function inside the function (async) and continue without waiting for a response

I googled and tried to do a task using the asyncio module, but `main` is still waiting for a response from the `func`

```
import asyncio
import datetime

async def func(delay):
    print('func started ' + datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M:%S'))
    await asyncio.sleep(delay)
    print('func finished ' + datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M:%S'))

async def main():
    print('main started ' + datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M:%S'))
    async_task = asyncio.get_event_loop().create_task(func(3))
    await async_task
    print('main finished ' + datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M:%S'))

asyncio.run(main())
```

```
>>> main started 13:37:21
>>> func started 13:37:21
>>> func finished 13:37:24
>>> main finished 13:37:24
```

Comment: That's what `await` keyword does - it causes you to wait for the tasks end.

Comment: Shift the `await async_task` to after the second print statement, you'll see that `func` prints after the conclusion of `main`.

Comment: @Shorn hahaha, I want to know how to execute a function without waiting for a response, and not print the word "main" later

Comment: @matszwecja then, is it the same thing to do a task and just execute a function? what to do then?

Comment: The function IS executing without waiting for a response. The function runs in the background already, its just that calling `await` forces the program to wait for the result. If you don't want it to wait for the result, don't call `await`. In the context of your question, if you don't call `await` at the end, the program finishes before `func` does and the second print statement from it won't occur.

Comment: @Shorn hahaha how stupid I am, everything worked out, thx